# Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions using STM32F429

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, ltdc

I want to store my logo image (which is 274 × 184 pixel) and six 120 × 120 icons in my background layer. Whenever my LCD turns on, it immediately shows my logo, which is in the center, and six icons (image1).

For this, I have set an array which is: `uint16_t RT[384000];` as my reference matrix (RT is an empty array the size of my LCD which is 800 * 480) to store my logo and six icons. I want to access my whole LCD to adjust the place of the six icons and my logo.

The problem is when I cast my logo which is stored in this type of data: `static const uint16_t LOGO [50416]`, which means it iss stored in my flash memory.

I used this order to cast LOGO into RT:

```
// refrence matrix:
for (i=0; i<384000; i++) {
  (*(__IO uint32_t *)(RT[i])  = (uint16_t)LOGO[i]);
}
```

Note: my LCD is configured as 16-bit to my STM32F429. I am using RGB565 color mode, with no external SDRAM.

The problem is when I compile the code; I get this error code:

```
Error: L6406E: No space in execution 
regions with .ANY selector matching 
main.o(.bss).

Error: L6407E: Sections of aggregate 
size 0xbb800 bytes could not fit into 
.ANY selector(s).
```

I will include my IROM and IRAM config as image2.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Here is my LTDC config for the logo:

```
LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_HorizontalStart = HSYNC_W + HBP;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_HorizontalStop = 800+ HSYNC_W + HBP - 1;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_VerticalStart   = VSYNC_W + VBP;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_VerticalStop    = 480+ VSYNC_W + VBP - 1;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_PixelFormat       = LTDC_Pixelformat_RGB565;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_ConstantAlpha     = 255;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_DefaultColorAlpha = 0;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_DefaultColorBlue  = 0;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_DefaultColorGreen = 0;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_DefaultColorRed = 0;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_BlendingFactor_1 = LTDC_BlendingFactor1_CA;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_BlendingFactor_2 = LTDC_BlendingFactor2_CA;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_CFBLineLength     = ((800 * 2) + 3);

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_CFBPitch          = (800 * 2);

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_CFBLineNumber     = 480;

LTDC_Layer_InitStruct.LTDC_CFBStartAdress = (uint16_t) RT[384000];

LTDC_LayerInit(LTDC_Layer1, &LTDC_Layer_InitStruct);
```

Here is my main.c:

```
LTDC_Cmd(ENABLE);
LTDC_LayerCmd(LTDC_Layer1, ENABLE); 
LTDC_ReloadConfig(LTDC_IMReload);
 
for (i=0; i<384000; i++) {
  (*(__IO uint32_t *) (RT[i] ) = (uint16_t)LOGO[i]);
}
     
LTDC_LayerPosition(LTDC_Layer1, 263, 148); // IN CENTER
LTDC_ReloadConfig(LTDC_IMReload);
// TO FADE AWAY SLOWLY
for (int y=0; y<=25; y++) {
  for (int x=(255-(10*y)); x>=0; x--) {
    LTDC_LayerAlpha( LTDC_Layer1, x);
    LTDC_ReloadConfig(LTDC_IMReload);
    Delay_us(100000);
```

NOTE: I have not configured my 6 icons, it have just not compiled to cast the logo into RT.

Image1:
[image: IMAGE 1]

I want to change my default background which is in black & white by using this order:

```
void LCD_SetBackColor(uint16_t Color) {
  CurrentBackColor = Color;
}
```

but it does not change anything.

Image2:

[image: IMAGE 2 MY STM32F429 CONFIGURATION]

Comment: I've worked on a project which used a similar MCU (STM32F427) and an almost identical size LCD. We had to use an "intelligent" LCD with its own framebuffee RAM built in (since the MCU doesn't have enough RAM) and not use a "dumb" LCD with the STM's LTDC module. The full screen image for the UI is built up in "stripes", each piece drawn and then sent over to the LCD one-by- one.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what LCD you're using?

Comment: Hi I am using 5" TFT lcd, I decided to use an external sdram.

Answer (score 1):

Your MCU has a total of 256 kilobytes of RAM.

It means you can't have an array of 750 kilobytes as the frame buffer.

You need to rethink what you want to do and how to achieve what you want to do with the hardware you have.

Comment: Hi I am using 5" TFT lcd, I decided to use an external sdram.

Comment: Hi I am using 5" TFT lcd, I decided to use an external sdram.